# Using NbClust on datasets that produce some negative eigenvalues. When to exclude data, when to force to positive, when to exclude test index?

Tags: r, clustering, multivariate-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, eigenvalues

Background on why I am using clustering:
I am analyzing data from a multistep biological experiment, where each step is done in batches of varying sizes. I want to account for any biases that might have been introduced by subtle technical differences in how the batches were processed.

There are about 600 samples, and each sample is a member of five different technical batches. Each technical batch variable has between 20 and 80 groups. The plan is to use BIC to select which of these variables (among many others) have an overall strong enough effect to include in the final model that I will use for analysis. However the high number of factor levels means that I cannot run the full model due to high dimensionality. I hope to mitigate this by grouping together similar technical batches.

How I am using clustering:
For each technical batch variable I fit a linear model. The coefficients of these linear models are then used for hierarchical clustering in order to group together similar technical batches. So for each factor level, I have a vector of 20,000 coefficients, representing the estimated effect of that level on 20,000 genes. In the past I have either set an arbitrary cutoff for the hierarchical clustering or just eyeballed it, but that is obviously not ideal. So this time I want to use an empirical method to estimate the ideal number of clusters/distance cutoff.

So for technical batch with 80 levels, I put into `NbClust` an 80x20,000 matrix. My struggles with adapting `NbClust` to work with bigger matrices are discussed in other threads (these focus on the programming side):

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57935571/rfast-hd-eigen-returns-nas-but-base-eigen-does-not
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57932385/differences-between-functions-to-get-variance-covariance-matrix-var-and-cova
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57683324/reducing-nbclust-memory-usage/57912351#57912351

The problem:
Some of the technical variables result in `NbClust` input matrices that give negative eigenvalues and eigenvectors. This prevents some NbClust indices from running (namely `ccc`, `scott`, `marriot`, `trcovw`,`tracew`, `friedman`, and `rubin`) and stops the whole function with the error `The TSS matrix is indefinite. There must be too many missing values. The index cannot be calculated`.

Possible solutions:

1. Dont use those indices on my data. This is a little inconvenient because of how NbClust is set up, I'd probably just exclude those tests from my copy.
2. Drop the negative eigenvectors associated with those eigenvalues and pick the clusters based on the remaining genes (~90% of them).
3. Force the negative eigenvectors a very small positive number.

Are these valid approaches? Are there other approaches that I am not thinking of? Remember that I am only using this to select an optimal number of clusters for a variable that I hope to be able to exclude anyway. So perhaps precision is not as important in my case, but obviously I want to make sure that everything I do is mathematically and theoretically valid and as precise as possible.

Comment: Use only other indices? Apparently they don't work?

Comment: Right, there is a subset of indices that require a positive-definite matrix of eigenvectors. The rest should work fine, although I am still testing.

Comment: A trivial, but common, cause are constant attributes, and duplicated attributes. In general I would suggest to rather investigate why this happens rather than hacking around it by forcing eigenvalues to be larger than 0 etc.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by constant and duplicated attributes. And where? In the matrix that produced the negative eigenvalues?

Comment: No, in the input data.

Comment: The data that I input into NbClust is a 38x2441 matrix of continuous numeric data. There are no missing values.

Comment: I said constant, and duplicate. Also, perfect correlation is as bad as duplicate. It can be sufficient if a large enough subset of the data exhibits this property.

Comment: Do you know a good way to test for that? Would a randomly selected subset be expected to show a high (how high?) correlation with another randomly selected subset? How many duplicated values would it take to cause a problem?

Comment: Well, if you get a zero column in the covariance matrix then you have such a data problem. If you get negative values on the diagonal, you have a numerical problem because these must be non-negative by definition.

Comment: The covariance matrix of what? I made a covariance matrix from the input data and there were no zeros in the entire matrix, nor were any of the columns or rows invariant. None of the values on the diagonal were less than zero.

Comment: Of a cluster, as used by NbClust. Because that is what's happening, isn't it?

Comment: Nothing has been clustered yet at the point where the negative eigenvalues are produced. This is at line 60 of the `NbClust` function.

Comment: From a quick look at this line, I'd say: don't use NbClust, it is probably incorrect. They forgot to center the matrix. It is also very badly implemented, doing expensive computations twice that you may not need at all.

Comment: Well, since it's a commonly used tool, the thing to do would be to fix it.

Comment: I'm not a R user. It's weird inconsistent "syntax" drives me crazy. Every R package is different, no two have the same API. There is a term four this: FUBAR, beyond all repair. It would be easier to begin from scratch rather than fix everything broken in CRAN.